# DELETE statement mysqli

Tags: mysqli

I am quite insecure about something. If I want to delete the entire table of my database, is the code under correct? or do I have to add some more code? does it need a while loop, or is there something I misunderstand?

del.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="del.php">
  <button type="button" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete">
</form>

<?php
    include 'connect.php';

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE * FROM numbers") or die($mysqli->error);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the wildcard character `*` ie,

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM numbers") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is my HTML form okay also, or do I need some more code there?

Comment: @NeKr:- Yes that looks ok to me but you can give it a try and see what you get :)

Comment: Do not need more code on the page? I am think the SQL is executed with this? I dont need fx $stmt->execute(); or something?

Comment: I will try when I come home from work. I hope that you see my message later. I am just gonna wait putting  tick for correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It must be `DELETE FROM numbers`

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM numbers") or die($mysqli->error);
```

And if you want to truncate you can have

```
TRUNCATE [TABLE] numbers
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is my HTML form okay also, or do I need some more code there? Do I call my php page correct from my html form?